# How to delete data older than some days in rocksdb or leveldb ?

Tags: leveldb, rocksdb

I want to create a tool to delete all of the data older than some days in rocksdb or leveldb, but i don't know how to start it.

Comment: so i assumed that you want data to have ```ttl``` ?

Comment: What is the layout of the data you are storing in the database?

Comment: What languages do you use?

Comment: I use golang if you mean programming lang

Comment: @sel-fish yes, i think ttl is what i wanted

Comment: @Michael add timestamp to leveldb/rocksdb record, and modify compact logic to drop expired record, which you can reference https://github.com/lotair/tair/tree/develop/src/storage/ldb/leveldb

Answer (score 2):

RocksDB has a specific database, called `Date_tiered DB`. You can specify the ttl with which u want to open the database. It basically shards the data that gets inserted into multiple CFs and Drops the CFs as a whole when ttl has expired. Note that, when the Db is opened second time with a different ttl, the expiry time of the data is calculated based on the new ones.

Alternatively, you can create your own `custom compaction filter` to remove the old data in compaction time. This actually saves the pain of issuing a delete and can be done as a background job.